# "These files can't be opened" error on ALL files after update

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, security, windows-server-2008-r2

Running Windows Server 2008 R2, and doing the latest updates for the last month.

Updates had downloaded and installed, although not entirely as I had postponed restarting and finishing the process.

Power was randomly lost. Upon rebooting updates were applied, although after logging in every file I try to open, even files that come with Windows such as cmd or regedit result in the error "These files can't be opened" due to my security settings.

I've tried changing settings in internet options to no avail.

Other things I have tried:

- Uninstalling updates
- Making a new local admin account
- Disabling UAC
- Last known good configuration

None of these have worked. Would anyone have a suggestion on how to save my install?

Win 2008 R2, SP1.

Answer (score 1):

System restore to a previous recovery point, or restore from backup.
"repair" install from server media.

Comment: no luck with either.

Comment: so are you saying a full restore from a previous backup does not solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm saying. After tryinig to uninstall some further updates and trying last known good configuration again I have a working system, although it looks like I have to install updates from the last 2 years....